# Webpack Module Federation loads chunks from wrong URL

Tags: reactjs, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-module-federation

I am building a project with webpack module federation with the following setup:

- React host (running on `localhost:3000`)
- Angular Remote 1 (running on `localhost:4201`)
- Angular Remote 2 (running on `localhost:4202`)

The goal is to get both remotes working. If I only run one of the and remove the other it is working perfectly.

The issue I am facing is that when the remotes are loaded, `__webpack_require__.p` is set by one of the remotes' script and therefore the other remote's chunk is loaded from the wrong url.

Here is the error I get:

[image: Remote loaded from wrong URL]

My module federation config is the following:

- React host:

```
.
.
.
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "react_host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        angular_remote_1: "angular_remote_1@http://localhost:4201/angular_remote_1.js",
        angular_remote_2: "angular_remote_2@http://localhost:4202/angular_remote_2.js"
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
.
.
.
```

- Angular Remote 1

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
    output: {
        publicPath: "auto",
        uniqueName: "angular_remote_1",
        scriptType: "text/javascript"
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "angular_remote_1",
            library: { type: "var", name: "angular_remote_1" },
            filename: "angular_remote_1.js",
            exposes: {
                './angularRemote1': './src/loadAngularRemote1.ts',
            },
            shared: ["@angular/core", "@angular/common", "@angular/router"]
        })
    ],
};
```

- Angular Remote 2

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
    output: {
        publicPath: "auto",
        uniqueName: "angular_remote_2",
        scriptType: "text/javascript"
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "angular_remote_2",
            library: { type: "var", name: "angular_remote_2" },
            filename: "angular_remote_2.js",
            exposes: {
                './angularRemote2': './src/loadAngularRemote2.ts',
            },
            shared: ["@angular/core", "@angular/common", "@angular/router"]
        })
    ],
};
```

Thins I have tried so far:

- Playing around with public path (between `auto` and hardcoded)
- Setting a custom `chunkLoadingGlobal` for both remotes (not the host)

The exact reproduction of this issue can be found here: https://github.com/BarniPro/react-host-angular-remotes-microfrontend

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be solved by setting the `topLevelAwait` [experiment](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experiments) to true in the remotes's `webpack.config.js`:

```
experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
},
```

This results in the two remotes loading in sync which prevents the paths from overriding each other.

Another update I had to make was disabling the `splitChunks` option in the remotes' optimization settings (see [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)):

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false, // This is also needed, but was added in the original question as well
    splitChunks: false,
}
```

The [Github repo](https://github.com/BarniPro/react-host-angular-remotes-microfrontend) has been updated with the working solution.